# How to close the popup window after facebook login and reload the parent window in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook

I need to open the facebook login through ajax in popup woindow. im getting the url from the response. after facebook login i need to close the popup window and reload the parent window.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = $("#facebook_login_container").find('a').attr('href');
    window.open(url,this.target);
    window.close();
});
```

here,consider the url as www.facebook.com.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can have this functionality much easier when you just use `FB.login` out of the JS SDK. If you don’t want to use that, you will have to give the login dialog a redirect address on your domain, that will get loaded into the popup after the user authenticated, that reloads the parent page and closes the popup.

Comment: @CBroe - Can you explain it or give example code Please

Comment: No. I you have _specific_ questions, ask them. Otherwise, please do your own research on the mentioned topics/keywords first.

Comment: @CBroe - Thanks. But i'm new to facebook integration. so only asked the sample code without using FB.login.

Comment: Apart from giving the redirect address (which you already should know how to do if you are building the login dialog yourself, since this parameter is a required one), this has little to do with FB integration, it’s basic JS related to window handling.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following in popup page, this is how I got it to work in my application,nothing worked except the uncommented lines and forget the commented lines,they are part of my testing:

```
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"  >
    function Close() {
        window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;
        document.location.href = document.location.href;
        //window.opener.location.reload(true);
        self.close();


       //winOpener = window.self.opener;
       //winOpener.location.reload();
       //window.close();
     }
   </script>
```